# What min-width should I set so that search icon does not go down in new line?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="http://wp/" id="searchfrm" name="searchfrm" class="search-form clearfix" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="hidden" id="post_type" name="post_type" value="post">
    <label>
        <h4 class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</h4>
        <input type="search" aria-labelledby="searchfrm" title="Search for:" id="search" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search …" class="search-field">
    </label>

    <button type="submit" name="button" class="search-button">
        <i id="submit-searchfrm" class="icon-search fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
    </button>

</form>
```

There is no min-width for input (class=search-field). When width is below certain level then icon is going into next line. There is enough space that both can fit together.

For example, where it was not fitting well in responsive design mode (Firefox), I gave input box width: 64% then it worked. But with this when sidebar is bigger in width then input box will be very smaller and there will be much gap between input box and search icon. So, looking for solution.

Comment: Not necessarily min-width, looking for any good solution.

Comment: `white-space:nowrap`?

Comment: Not getting how it would help me, but is there a way to tell take space left after this element?

Comment: I used this: `.content-wrapper .search-field {
    width:calc(~"100% - 42px");
}`
I had different settings for header search form and sidebar search form. Here I am doing minus total width from Search Icon.

Comment: For info, extra character "~" with quote is due to LESS CSS.